# How can i display element over body, when body is blured?

Tags: html, css

I have a problem, I'm trying to display div over the blurred body, but I can't really make it work. I've tried adding z-index to the div but it doesn't seem to be working.

Heres what I've tried:

```css
body {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    background: black;
    color: white;
    border: none;
    cursor: default;
    filter: blur(11px);
}

#foo {
  z-index: 10;
}
```

```html
<div id="foo">
  Random Text
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have blurred the parent, all descendants will be blurred as well. To achieve a similar effect you have to:

- create and blur a `div`, say `#bar`, which will be a sibling to `#foo` instead.
- give `#foo` a higher `z-index` than `#bar` and ensure it's positioned *(not `position: static`)*.

**Example:**

```css
/* ----- CSS ----- */
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

#bar {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  background: black;
  color: white;
  border: none;
  cursor: default;
  filter: blur(11px);
  z-index: 0;
}


#foo {
  color: red;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 10;
}
```

```html
<!----- HTML ----->
<div id="bar"></div>
<div id="foo">
  Random Text
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You always need to define a `position` to your `z-index`ed selector

Answer (score 0):

The Random text is black just like the body background and you should define the body z-index lower than #foo.
Hopes this helps :)